# How to solve method overloading in subclass (Declaration of ... should be compatible with )?

Tags: php, inheritance, static, warnings, overloading

The example should demonstrate it best:

```
class Generic {
    protected $a;
    protected $b;

    protected final function __construct($a,$b) {
        $this->a = $a;
        $this->b = $b;
        echo $this->a." ".$this->b;
    }

    public static function create($a,$b) {
        return new self($a,$b);
    }


}

class Wanter extends Generic {
    public static function create($b) {
        return parent::create("I want",$b);
    }
}

Generic::foo("I need","coffee!");
Wanter::foo("coffee!");
```

Expected output:

```
I need coffee!I want coffee!
```

Actual output:

> **Warning**: Declaration of Wanter::create($b) should be compatible
>   with Generic::create($a, $b) in **[...][...]** on line **25** I need coffee!I want coffee!

It is obvious what this should do (as it does). However I want to run this without throwing warnings of course. How to implement this without warning?

Comment: `public static function create($a,$b)` your missing an argument for the child method.

Comment: Yeah but thats the point. That argument is not needed and `create()` is possible with a single argument, because the subclass "knows" argument $a.

Comment: Making child classes more restrictive than the classes they extend is a violation of the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). Traditional method overriding isn't the pattern you want to use for something like this.

Comment: @iainn Thanks thats good to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be obvious but the child method definition must match that of the parent, so you are missing an argument.

What I would do is this:

```
class Generic {
    protected $a;
    protected $b;

    protected final function __construct($a,$b) {
        $this->a = $a;
        $this->b = $b;
        echo $this->a." ".$this->b;
    }

    public static function create($a,$b) {
        return new self($b,$a); //reverse arguments
    }


}

class Wanter extends Generic {
    public static function create($a, $b="I want") {
        return parent::create($b,$a);
    }
}
```

Note that I changed the order of the arguments, this way the one with the default is the second argument.

You could do this just in the child, but it might be somewhat confusing, if the order is different then the parent class.

That said, something like a factory method may be more appropriate in this instance.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_(object-oriented_programming)

Besides a factory pattern I am not sure how important it is for you to have the static Create method.  The constructor offers more flexibility when needing things like polymorphism.  For example something like this would be acceptable

```
abstract class Generic {
   protected $a;
   protected $b;

   protected function create($a,$b) {
        $this->a = $a;
        $this->b = $b;
        echo $this->a." ".$this->b;
    }

}

class Wanter extends Generic {
    public function __construct($a) {
        return $this->create("I want",$a);
    }
}
```

Then each child can define it's own constructor, with its own set of required arguments.

Comment: plus one purely for _It should be obvious_

Comment: Yea problems like this are often an indicator that the wrong pattern is being used for the class structure.  If it was just he constructor their wouldn't be so much of an issue